# How to translate local json data

Tags: json, angular

navbar.component.html

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" class="{{menuItem.class}} nav-item">
                <a [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" class="nav-link">{{menuItem.title}}</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" (click)="showModal()"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

navbar.comomponent.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

declare interface RouteInfo {
    path: string;
    title: string;
    class: string;
}
export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
    { path: '/home', title: 'Home', class: '' },
    { path: '/buyer_registration', title: 'Buyer Registration',  class: '' },
    { path: '/rate_contract', title: 'Rate Contract', class: '' },
    { path: '/login', title: 'Login', class: '' },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})

export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  menuItems: any[];

  constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('English');
    translate.use('English');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.menuItems = ROUTES.filter(menuItem => menuItem);
  }
}
```

How to translate local JSON data?
I already have an en and fr JSON file in my local

Answer (score 0):

With ngx-translate you can do exactly that.
You will find a step by step introduction here:

[ngx-translate Documentation](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)

Comment: export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
    { path: '/home', title: 'Home', class: '' },
    { path: '/buyer_registration', title: 'Buyer Registration',  class: '' },
    { path: '/rate_contract', title: 'Rate Contract', class: '' },
    { path: '/login', title: 'Login', class: '' },
];    I have to do with this perticule...translation is working fine in my local

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem as well.

What I finally did was use [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core).
It's easy to use!

[Here is working example.](https://stackblitz.com/github/ngx-translate/example)